# Interrupting open() with SIGALRM

Tags: linux, signals, posix

We have a legacy embedded system which uses SDL to read images and fonts from an NFS share.

If there's a network problem, TTF_OpenFont() and IMG_Load() hang essentially forever. A test application reveals that open() behaves in the same way.

It occurred to us that a quick fix would be to call alarm() before the calls which open files on the NFS share. The man pages weren't entirely clear whether open() would fail with EINTR when interrupted by SIGALRM, so we put together a test app to verify this approach. We set up a signal handler with sigaction::sa_flags set to zero to ensure that SA_RESTART was not set.

The signal handler was called, but open() was not interrupted. (We observed the same behaviour with SIGINT and SIGTERM.)

I suppose the system treats open() as a "fast" operation even on "slow" infrastructure such as NFS.

Is there any way to change this behaviour and allow open() to be interrupted by a  signal?

Comment: Are you sure those signals weren't blocked during the call to open()?

Comment: @pilcrow: the signals weren't blocked: I incremented a counter in the signal handler to verify the signal handler was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The man pages weren't entirely clear whether open() would fail with
>   EINTR when interrupted by SIGALRM, so we put together a test app to
>   verify this approach.

`open(2)` is a slow syscall (slow syscalls are those that can sleep forever, and can be awaken when, and if, a signal is caught in the meantime) only for some file types. In general, opens that block the caller until some condition occurs are usually interruptible. Known examples include opening a FIFO (named pipe), or (back in the old days) opening a physical terminal device (it sleeps until the modem is dialed).

NFS-mounted filesystems probably don't cause `open(2)` to sleep in an interruptible state. After all, you are most likely opening a regular file, and in that case `open(2)` will not be interruptable.

> Is there any way to change this behaviour and allow open() to be
>   interrupted by a signal?

I don't think so, not without doing some (non-trivial) changes to the kernel.

I would explore the possibility of using `setjmp(3)` / `longjmp(3)` (see the manpage if you're not familiar; it's basically non-local gotos). You can initialize the environment buffer before calling `open(2)`, and issue a `longjmp(3)` in the signal handler. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static jmp_buf jmp_env;

void sighandler(int signo) {
    longjmp(jmp_env, 1);
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigact.sa_handler = sighandler;
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sigact, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setjmp(jmp_env) == 0) {
        /* First time through
         * This is where we would open the file
         */

        alarm(5);

        /* Simulate a blocked open() */
        while (1)
            ; /* Intentionally left blank */

        /* If open(2) is successful here, don't forget to unset
         * the alarm
         */

        alarm(0);
    } else {
        /* SIGALRM caught, open(2) canceled */
        printf("open(2) timed out\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works by saving the context environment with the help of `setjmp(3)` before calling `open(2)`. `setjmp(3)` returns 0 the first time through, and returns whatever value was passed to `longjmp(3)` otherwise.

Please be aware that this solution is not perfect. Here are some points to keep in mind:

- There is a window of time between the call to `alarm(2)` and the call to `open(2)` (simulated here with `while (1) { ... }`) where the process may be preempted for a long time, so there is a chance the alarm expires before we actually attempt to open the file. Sure, with a large timeout such as 2 or 3 seconds this will most likely not happen, but it's still a race condition.
- Similarly, there is a window of time between successfully opening the file and canceling the alarm where, again, the process may be preempted for a long time and the alarm may expire before we get the chance to cancel it. This is slightly worse because we have already opened the file so we will "leak" the file descriptor. Again, in practice, with a large timeout this will likely never happen, but it's a race condition nevertheless.
- If the code catches other signals, there may be another signal handler in the midst of execution when `SIGALRM` is caught. Using `longjmp(3)` inside the signal handler will destroy the execution context of these other signal handlers, and depending on what they were doing, very nasty things may happen (inconsistent state if the signal handlers were manipulating other data structures in the program, etc.). It's as if it started executing, and suddenly crashed somewhere in the middle. You can fix it by: a) carefully setting up all signal handlers such that `SIGALRM` is blocked before they are invoked (this ensures that the `SIGALRM` handler does not begin execution until other handlers are done) and b) blocking these other signals before catching `SIGALRM`. Both actions can be accomplished by setting the  `sa_mask` field of `struct sigaction` with the necessary mask (the operating system atomically sets the process's signal mask to that value before beginning execution of the handler and unsets it before returning from the handler). OTOH, if the rest of the code doesn't catch signals, then this is not a problem.
- `sleep(3)` may be implemented with `alarm(2)`, and `alarm(2)` and `setitimer(2)` share the same timer; if other portions in the code make use of any of these functions, they will interfere and the result will be a huge mess.

Just make sure you weigh in these disadvantages before blindly using this approach. The use of `setjmp(3)` / `longjmp(3)` is usually discouraged and makes programs considerably harder to read, understand and maintain. It's not elegant, but right now I don't think you have a choice, unless you're willing to do some core refactoring in the project.

If you do end up using `setjmp(3)`, then at the very least document these limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a strategy of using a separate thread to do the open so the main thread is not held up longer than desired.

Comment: This is what I did. It works well, but this sort of ugly workaround shows that the original design was not the best. In the end I swapped out the NFS code for HTTP access, which is much more well behaved.